# Multiprocessing in Python is slower than single

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I want to animate some line drawing smoothly, and decided to do it with Python, which I did not know good. I now try to accelerate the skimage.draw.line. My multiprocessing attempt did not deliver the expected result (next to multithreading).

This is the basic part of the code, which reproduces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import multiprocessing

def draw(r0, c0, r1, c1):
    for counter in range(0, 10000):
        rr, cc = skimage.draw.line(r0, c0, r1, c1)
    return (rr, cc)

def width_heigth(img, shape):
    return int(img.shape[shape])-1

if __name__=='__main__':

    img = np.zeros([1000, 1000, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
    width = width_heigth(img, 1)
    height = width_heigth(img, 0)
    centerx = int(img.shape[1] / 2)
    centery = int(img.shape[0] / 2)

    start = timer()

    draw(centerx, centery, width, height);
    draw(centerx, centery, width, height);

    timea = ("a:", (timer() - start) * 1000)
    print(timea)

    start = timer()

    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=draw, args=(centerx, centery, width, height,))
    t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=draw, args=(centerx, centery, width, height,))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    timeb = ("b:", (timer() - start) * 1000)
    print(timeb)
```

('a:', 108.91789989545941)
('b:', 212.72159996442497)

I would have expected multiprocessing to be faster.

Comment: You're multiplying by `1000` as if `timer` returned milliseconds, but from what I can see in the docs, it returns seconds. If we're talking in milliseconds then the difference is quite small and can be attributed to the overheads in creating a child process. Multiprocessing isn't free and doesn't payoff for tasks under a certain size.

Comment: @RichardDunn ok thanks, good point. I increased the range of the counter and _Voilà_ - it was quicker after adding a factor of 100 runs. Since I just draw a picture this is the wrong approach. Any idea how to draw a line faster?

Comment: maybe you should consider using another drawing library. Note that if the lines are small the overhead of calling a native function from Python might be the issue. In this case, Cython/C/C++ are the way to go. One alternative library is Cairo (which has a Python module). Besides, note that anti-aliasing can be expensive so disabling this can be faster (though also uglier).

Comment: If you want a very fast solution, then you should direct GPU rendering. GPUs can draw about a billion line per second. This can be done in PyOpenGL + Numpy (though it is a bit slower than native languages). This is also lower-level so more complex.